# What is the significance of ARN vs URL in AWS context?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-sqs

They can't be used interchangeably, I believe. Have seen ARN being used for permission related usecase, where as URL for endpoint trigger.
Is this correct? Why did AWS come up with ARN, if it already had URL or vice-versa?

Answer (score 0):

You're only comparing it to an endpoint, but all resources have ARNs, even those which do not have a URL, a DynamoDB table for example.

This document will explain in more detail:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference-arns.html